# Why don't my objects remain still in my camera footage despite having good tracking?

Tags: animation, camera, tracking

Good day, I am having an annoying issue with Blender's tracking. I am trying to motion track footage, and every time I do it, I get a low Solving number of below 0.5 Px. Despite this, every time I set up a tracking scene and try to align the mesh. My objects keep moving, they don't remain rock solid like I want. Honestly, it's quite annoying. Does anyone have any idea why? [image]

Here's what the solving error looks like, with my trackers.

I can't post a video, but basically imagine the Shadow catcher and the cube that come with 'Setup Tracking Scene' but instead of remaining still when playing the  footage, they keep stuttering back and forth annoyingly. It's quite demotivating. I don't know the camera settings, as I know that will help immensely in tracking. It's a footage I downloaded online.

Comment: Try playing around with different values for Keyframe A and Keyframe B. They don't have to be the first and last frame of your footage, they can be any two frames.
Try making the values closer to each other, like frame 60 for Keyframe A, and 120 for Keyframe B. Click "solve" again and see if it's better. If it's better but still not good enough, try again with different values.

Comment: I'll try to do so, I also found out that when I use the Tripod option in the Solver, it gives me the result I want but it puts the px amount to insanely high.

Comment: Update: I had to set the floor and wall by setting them using the trackers, so much appreciated to everyone for the comments. The motion tracking now is much better.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but I remember seeing people refusing anything above 0.3 and sometimes even 0.1.

Once you solved your camera, have you selected three of your markers' empties in the 3D scene and set their orientation using the Movie Clip Editor > Tracking mode > Sidebar > Solve Tab > Orientation panel ?

[image]

This trick is shown in this video: [Camera Tracking with Blender for Beginners! (VFX Tutorial) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O67P0uzbQBk). He uses "Floor" in his video, but I guess yours would need "Wall".

Comment: Much appreciated, I found out that using fSpy might help with the tracking and apparently the Tripod option in the Solver does do what I want l, but it messed it up by increasing the px amount.

Comment: Update: I had to set the floor and wall by setting them using the trackers, so much appreciated to everyone for the comments. The motion tracking now is much better.  Thank you.